# If we know the density of $f(x\mid y=1)$ and $f(x\mid y=0)$, how to get the distribution of $f(x\mid y)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

For random variable $X\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$ and $Y$, here $Y\sim \operatorname{Ber}(p)$ and
$$X\mid Y\sim Y N(0,\sigma_1^2)+(1-Y)N(0,\sigma_2^2)$$

Another question is if I know the density of $f(x\mid y=1)$ and $f(x\mid y=0)$, how to get the distribution of  $f(x\mid y)$? Is it

$$f(x\mid y)=\Pr(Y=1)f(x\mid y=1)+\Pr(Y=0)f(x\mid y=0) \text{?}$$

Comment: Your equality is wrong. Namely, $\mathbb P(X\mid Y)$ has no sense a priori, and if you mean $$\mathbb P\{X\in A\mid Y\}=\mathbb P\{X\in A\mid Y=0\}+\mathbb P\{X\in A\mid Y=1\},$$ then the LHS is a r.v. whereas the RHS is a number. Nevertheless, what is true is $$\mathbb E[\mathbb P\{X\in A\mid Y\}]=\mathbb P\{X\in A\mid Y=0\}\mathbb P\{Y=0\}+\mathbb P\{X\in A\mid Y=1\}\mathbb P\{Y=1\}.$$

Comment: @Surb Thanks. But if I know the density of $p(x|y=1)$ and $p(x|y=0)$, how to get the distribution of  $p(x|y)$?